How to choose controller when using Nav2's driveOnHeading commander API?
I am trying to use the driveOnHeading function from Nav2's simple commander API to make a robot advance while completely ignoring the local costmap. However, it seems I cannot pass a controller_id when using this API. I want to use a specific controller that has the obstacle critic turned off. Is there some other way to do it? Thanks in advance.

Drive on Heading does a simple controller that accelerates with the chosen profile to the maximum speed, and then ramps back down to stop at the distance. It uses a standard trapezoidal profile. See the Drive on Heading configuration guide entry for the parameters to set the acceleration and maximum speed!

Thanks, however. my problem is that DriveOnHeading fails/aborts when the robot is in close proximity to an obstacle. I want to use DriveOnHeading while completely ignoring obstacles. It seems there is no way to configure the controller, e.g. with a disabled obstacle critic, when using DriveOnHeading.

Example error:
[component_container_isolated-2] [WARN] [1733220291.571959692] [behavior_server]: Collision Ahead - Exiting DriveOnHeading

Ah. There is currently no ability to disable collision checking since that is a safety feature. We could though make it a parameter and make the check for collisions optional. Would you be open to implementing that for spin/drive on heading? [1] https://github.com/ros-navigation/navigation2/blob/main/nav2_behaviors/include/nav2_behaviors/plugins/drive_on_heading.hpp#L141

Yes absolutely.
